# Ruby 1.9.2 eventmachine installation error on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, gcc, eventmachine

When I'm trying to install eventmachine on my OSX I got this error.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ncharass/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
g++ -I. -I/Users/ncharass/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/ncharass/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/ncharass/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe     -o binder.o -c binder.cpp
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wshorten-64-to-32’
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ncharass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@comp.com/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ncharass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@comp.com/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

And this is my g++ version.

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.4/4.7.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.4
Configured with: ../gccgo/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,go --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.0 20110520 (experimental) (GCC)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking around on Google it seems like this is a compiler mis-match between what was used for Ruby and what's getting used for EventMachine.  There is a good writeup at [Instant Badger](http://instantbadger.blogspot.com/2011/11/porting-rails-23-app-to-ruby-19.html) which may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been stumbling around google and found nothing.